# Hive query to transform columns into rows

Tags: hive

I am looking for a hive query which can do the below transformation on the below table
**Input:**

```
cust1 jan 100
cust1 feb 110
cust2 mar 150
cust2 apr 140
cust2 feb 170
```

**Result:**

```
cust1 100, 110
cust2 170, 150, 140
```

Comment: collect_list (your_column)

Answer (score 0):

The collect_list() can be used to perform the operation:

**Query**

```
select col1,collect_list(col3) from tabledata group by col1;
```

**Output**

```
cust1  [100,110]
cust2  [150,140,170]
```